# Why does addEventListener() only get suggestions for the fullscreenchange and fullscreenerror events on an element from document.querySelector?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, addeventlistener

What I want (an example of all the events suggested for `addEventListener` on the `document` object):
[image: 1. It is what i want]

What I have (events suggested for `addEventListner` on the object returned from my `document.querySelector` query (only `fullscreenchange` and `fullscreenerror`)):
[image: 2. there is no suggestion at this]

I want suggestions as shown in the first image.

Here's a transcription of the above images so you can try for yourself:

```js
const titleElement = document.querySelector("#title");

document.addEventListener("", (ev) => {});
// ^lots of suggested event names

titleElement.addEventListener("", (ev) => {});
// ^only the `fullscreenchange` and `fullscreenerror` events are suggested
```

Comment: Welcome! I improved your question for you by being more specific and descriptive about observations. Please take a moment to look at the [revision history](/posts/75329414/revisions) to see what I changed and learn [ask] better questions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to typing. [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) is only guaranteed to return an element of type [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element), although, of course, it can return an object of a subtype of `Element`. But for the type definitions in `lib.dom.ts`, `Element` is only defined to have those two events (`fullscreenchange` and `fullscreenerror`) on them- probably because those are the only two events that are valid for all possible `Element` subtypes.

To solve your problem, you can pass the type you expect as a generic argument to the `querySelector` call, like this:

```js
document.querySelector<HTMLHeadingElement>("#title")
```

which will type the returned object as `HTMLHeadingElement | null`.

Alternatively, you can add a type assertion to tell the TypeScript compiler or VS Code the exact type you expect that queried element to be.

In TypeScript, you can do a type assertion with the `as` keyword like this (you need to add `| null` yourself if you want it):

```js
const titleElement = document.querySelector("#title") as HTMLHeadingElement;
// or whatever HTML type your `#title`-IDed element is.
```

In JavaScript, you can use JSDoc comments to make type hints that VS Code and other tools will recognize:

```js
/** @type {HTMLHeadingElement} */
const titleElement = document.querySelector("#title");
```

Or, you can wrap your usage of the object returned from the query with a type check:

```js
const titleElement = document.querySelector("#title");
if (titleElement instanceof HTMLHeadingElement) {
  titleElement.addEventListever("click", (ev) => {
    console.log("hello world!");
  });
}
```

The TypeScript language server that powers IntelliSense in VS Code will know that inside that if-block, the type of `titleElement` must be at least `HTMLHeadingElement` (or whatever type you specify in the `instanceof` check) because of the `instanceof` check. You can read more about [the `instanceof` operator on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof).

To get a list of all existing HTML elements, one place to look is [MDN's HTML Element Reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element), or you can just type `HTML` in your file in VS Code and trigger autocomplete suggestions.