# It doesn't give me the suggestions in javascript inside quotes " "

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

It happens that when I give control + space inside the ""
It is not giving me suggestions to add, not even when I use the button, for example. and I want to see style, style does not appear, I must write it manually and I see that there are other people where they give these suggestions. Before, I was achieving it by giving control + k + M and placing javascript but now it seems that it does not work, please help, I want to write code faster

here the suggestions for the event do not appear, it is not giving me suggestions and neither when I use the button.style it should give me style in suggestions but I have to place it manually even when I place button.style.color it does not appear that I must write everything manually and I see that it should appear since it did before

```
boton.addEventListener("", (" here he doesn't give me suggestions Ctrl + space ") => {
  let fechaActual = 2024;
  let guardado = fechaActual - fecha.value;

  if (guardado > 18) {
    nombreAprobado.textContent = `${nombre.value} Puedes obtener la licencia tienes ${guardado} años`;
  } else {
    nombreAprobado.textContent = `No puedes tener licencia tienes ${guardado} años`;
  }
});
```

[image]

I was achieving it by giving control + k + M and placing javascript but now it doesn't seem to work please help

Comment: This is a question about VS code, not javascript. Boton probably isn't an HTML Element, which is why it won't give you suggestions. Can you show us the code you use to define boton?

Comment: @JacobBelanger It must be a element if they can use `addEventListener()` on it.

Comment: @Barmar, you're assuming he ran the code and it worked, which he didn't specify

Comment: Add a `.` after `boton.style`. Otherwise it's looking for other properties that contain `style`.

Comment: Well what is a quoted string supposed to mean in the formal argument list of a function?

Comment: @JacobBelanger Look at the completion it DID show, `computedStyleMap`. It says `(method) Element.computedStyleMap()` so it knows it's an Element.

Comment: You're asking for it to give suggestions for event names in the first argument of `addEventListener()`?

Comment: Also inside a quoted string, VS Code thinks you're, well, inside a quoted string. Completions don't really make sense, because while you *might* be putting JavaScript source code inside the string, you might also be putting the name of your favorite food or a story about your dog. It's a string, and it can contain anything.

Comment: @Pointy I'm guessing the `""` they're talking about is specifically the first argument to `addEventListener()`. Ideally it should have all the common event names as completions there.

Comment: <a class="carnet__enviar" href="#">Calcular</a>

I understand, it's that when I give ctrl to
 button.addEventListener("click" , the word click does not appear as a suggestion within the quotes when doing control + space, nor when I use the button.style does style not appear as a suggestion, why?

Comment: But I have seen the tutorial that I am following, if it gives you the suggestions between the quotes, or it gives you the style to change it without having to write it completely, and I think it should work but it is not giving it, why? Does it provide you with this information by giving it control+space inside an element like quotes " " or by using a style class?

Comment: when I do button.style. <--- you should give me suggestions and you act like you don't know

Comment: @Pointy Yes, yes, that's it, it should give me all the suggestions of the first argument within the function button.addEventListener("click" click is something that I place manually and it is not being suggested by the visual code and much less the style, it is as if that is not existed, I know it can be done, I have seen it and I have been trying to solve it all day, because it doesn't give me these suggestions and it does for other people.

Comment: we need a [mre]. how is `boton` defined? For one thing, you're not going to get any good intellisense if `boton` doesn't have a proper type annotation, and if you don't specify what event you're listening to. the type of the callback function depends on the event being listened to. also, read https://stackoverflow.com/q/75329414/11107541.

Comment: @starball Hey, thank you very much, you have helped me, I have never used this platform, I don't know how to return the favor by giving you a like or closing this as solved by you, thank you, thank you very much, I was able to solve my error this way

const uno = document.querySelector(".uno") as HTMLButtonElement;
const dos = document.querySelector(".dos") as HTMLButtonElement;
const resultados = document.querySelector(".resultado") as HTMLHtmlElement;

uno.addEventListener('', (ev) => {
 
});

dos.addEventListener('', (ev) => {
  
});

resultados.addEventListener('')

Comment: const uno = document.querySelector(".uno") as HTMLButtonElement;
const dos = document.querySelector(".dos") as HTMLButtonElement;
const resultados = document.querySelector(".resultado") as HTMLHtmlElement;

uno.addEventListener('', (ev) => {
 
});

dos.addEventListener('', (ev) => {
  
});

resultados.addEventListener('')